# How to check for frequencies with stronger signal in FM radio

Tags: frequency-modulation

I'm making a radio player using si4703 IC. I read RDS data to know the radio station name, PI code, etc.

I also get the list of alternative frequencies (AF) that the radio station send via RDS. However, in many cases this list is not very good because it doesn't include frequencies of the same station in a region which is close to mine one. However, this other frequencies have the same PI code and are, indeed, the same radio station transmitting the same audio content.

However, my car's radio is capable of switching to this frequencies not included in AF frequencies without interrupting what I'm listening, so it is not making a FM band scan to find this other frequency.

How does my car make this? Does it have a second FM receiver IC just to make frequencies scans?

Comment: Yes, it is quite common for car radios with such features to have two tuners.

Comment: They also use it to search for things like traffic announcements and other programmes of the same type.